# TypeScript: Extract object properties with dynamic output type and generic reusable interface

Tags: typescript, generics, types

it's hard to pick a proper summary, so let me try to explain my issue. I have a bunch of classes and each of them has a toJSON method that converts the class to its json representation. I want to add a new optional argument to each of those methods that allows me to return only a subset of the classes attributes instead all of them. The return type of that method should change accordingly to the properties that the developer picked.

I want to make this type-safe, but I have not reached a point which serves my needs fully. Short example what is missing:

```
interface IUser {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

const fullUser = user.toJson(); // full "IUser"
const truncatedUser = user.toJson({ attributes: ['name'] }); // Pick<IUser, 'name'>

fullUser.id // works
truncatedUser.id // should throw an error, but tsc compiles
```

Full example what I have implemented so far.

```
// Using the generic here, because I want to pass interface IUser, or IABC, or IDEF etc
interface IJSONExportOptions<Type> {
  /** A list of object properties that are included in the the resulting JSON.  */
  attributes?: (keyof Type)[];
}

interface IUser {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
}

class User {
  private id: string;
  private name: string;
  private age: number;

  constructor() {
    this.id = '1';
    this.name = 'Jon Doe';
    this.age = 20;
  }

  toJSON(opts?: IJSONExportOptions<IUser>) {
    const fullObj: IUser = {
      id: this.id,
      name: this.name,
      age: this.age,
    };

    if (!opts?.attributes?.length) {
      return fullObj as Pick<IUser, keyof IUser>;
    }

    const truncatedUser: Partial<Pick<IUser, keyof IUser>> = {};
    for (const key of opts?.attributes) {
      const val = fullObj[key];
      truncatedUser[key] = val;
    }
    return truncatedUser as Pick<IUser, keyof IUser>;
  }
}

const user = new User()
const fullUser = user.toJSON();

console.log(fullUser.age);

const truncatedUser = user.toJSON({ attributes: ['name'] });

console.log(truncatedUser.age); // I want that tsc throws an error here, but also that my IDE does not provide autocomplete for "undefined" properties
```

In case this is important, code is using typescript 4.4.3 (upgrading is an option).

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Rewrite with a generic parameter: https://tsplay.dev/mq0MJN

Comment: Thanks, this solution works! Can you explain this line `Keys extends keyof IUser = keyof IUser` ? I'd like to understand it fully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very first thing that comes to mind is rewriting the interface to take the keys instead of the type as a whole:

```
interface IJSONExportOptions<Keys extends string> {
  /** A list of object properties that are included in the the resulting JSON.  */
  attributes?: Keys[];
}
```

Then we can use a generic parameter that defaults to `keyof IUser`:

```
  toJSON<Keys extends keyof IUser = keyof IUser>(
    opts?: IJSONExportOptions<Keys>,
  ): Pick<IUser, Keys> {
```

So if there's no `attributes`, TypeScript will default to `keyof IUser` since it can't infer `Keys`. [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-parameter-defaults)

And lastly we could use an assertion:

```
return truncatedUser as Pick<IUser, Keys>;
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIFUDO1kG8BQyywAJgFzKZhSgDmA3IciHALYQVU0gNNy0dmAV1YAjaIwC++fAHpZyLHWRgAFigEhowBMnVQIAGmTiEcIdjTIA7nHAqA9sgAOcTJmLho8JGizRjByg0AEEAIQBhQODUABEAUQAxZAgwBHxQSFhEFFQAKQBlAHkAOXiAD2cgsCLnMGAHEEwAHgBpCABPDwhyyBASDy46AD48JlkAKgnkEOQAG2AqZAcYZdEAKwgEMBcoB2doeogPNTgduANPBDmhEggSTxV1J5QDTCE5+p5kQtKAOiIE1kfDA1GAoiEkEwAH4KO0ugBtAC6UhkmW8OT82GCBCIpE4YJ4jCILHYBO4vCI-EEIBE4igqPw1zcHn8OKYzhoADczih8ZRCZTdsAeZBmGxBEMiRzubzkNSKLSxBIZEQEI0uEJtkEABQASjGRCIakWf1IyAAvMgAEQARmtxKNJswf1JKCt1ryjWQsQcEAdTGNqlN1MtyAATAAGR3SJhgBy-EptTrdXoQfoeADWnRWWJwVuzHVzGGxwx1geWdRhFHyxTKlWqtXqGuTXWGhiYeooAAUdJnmiWAsh4ZhRrijeqmjsYB85kUNjW2WHx0biOQnqbSB3VySJRRna6JdudwqNy7qceiJJGBXgKsdQBCfZgGF-M5giFQ6F-Obp2hqA0VyNAwwCEKAQGQGc5jnDZ5Q8XsEH7QcoGMQtizZYZHSvVUJw1HZqCEEAzEgEg2R7C56jgOZmgQpC2VQnNVmQ4ZRitXBrwrGAgmQHVJyWQtllWZ9X3fGhP2OQCKzVPDkB5OYwygmD1gRQsUSklQoEI4j7jZFTOiRMM5Kw5BY1XECwIggiiN5UjsTg5BaIHejhxTTCmGkWM+J2Cx82YCBrEUbF9UYLzINnJcrR8qA-njRNgpkPiHF-H8HFoHVFLZN8BD1G9Qqs7TbN8qKYoTOsdVweVQTEyFjgoBFrTda0DMkHKEo1JKIBStL8pszLqVaoA)

Answer (score 0):

try this out: [ts-code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.4.4#code/C4TwDgpgBAggTnAhiAogGwgWwgO2AHhgD4oBeWKCAD2FwBMBnKOCROgexzRCgAoBLHADMIcKABUAlAG0AulAD8EqAC4oOCADdRAKB2DacIYgDG0AJIApAMoB5AHIoqYdnGC2wwfpwb5xJAG8dKChEYGA4fgAjAFdaBgU1cQBuHQBfPQNRYzMocwBVBlEoIJD+OkSoBgjBAHNUkJxEbErqyJx64NDaiEqcGMwo0VSMnRM0RAYmQuLSqDBIzTDocrU2uob5xeX1Zog1mo7Nhf4l2m799QGhuFSukx8ImJNgV15JEq6Q4AALfgYAHTlMhQADkAEZQZtvn9AU1sCDQZZOFAACLsCBQr5QX7-AGIHoggBMAAZNqNvuwbA4-JQaPQmLwANYQEDsIR5GZwGSyIi8dieBJqKx2RzOVzuTzeHC+fwfOYhB4y4BQIQxNBoWxRABWwq5IIVISgqxxsKBdAANNjGns1Li4XsrUajQTLvb8T0nUa0ndnfwObwAIQC4AJfHhSKxeIKAEYDq-eXW5gQYAxOA4VXqzU66FQClGpXVHFwGI4EzLOhctSIHA8cgBH16Z1CVx8Qsqlk8dlQENhsI1KMQJgKJRyRPOxWPKBLNAgtUarXa6Sd2S574lssVrnL1nycgz3MZZ0sVPp4ul8u0StFMSTKAABX4JiZ+AKN4tsAQyHQWFwBH8RDkukejtlAMQ3iCGgAO5QFy7x3GMU7zmg+rkOBogAq81L2PBUAAPR4ZmGpQAARG+ogkYhyrnpuV6oWBN6YVSoq8AEoQRtEcRDmo0igvCmLyGkkh3IW7AYLG7C1LwTy0RA14Ya6wlUQwYkQBJUnIVyHoQEpOiaYxwIEVAUGuEyDA6DJl5yVphmEQwPzsOqdCmnA7AwTWlAIK4H5RjiDAmFADyYGA-AYAwQA)

```
type ArrayElement<A> = A extends readonly (infer T)[] ? T : never

interface IJSONExportOptions<T> {
  attributes?: T;
}

interface IUser {
  id?: string;
  name?: string;
  age?: number;
}

class User {
  private id: string;
  private name: string;
  private age: number;

  constructor() {
    this.id = '1';
    this.name = 'Jon Doe';
    this.age = 20;
  }

  toJSON<T extends (keyof IUser)[]>(opts?: IJSONExportOptions<T>) {
    const fullObj: IUser = {
      id: this.id,
      name: this.name,
      age: this.age,
    };

    if (!opts?.attributes?.length) {
      return fullObj;
    }

    const truncatedUser: any = {};

    for (const key of opts?.attributes ?? []) {
      const val = fullObj[key];
      truncatedUser[key] = val;
    }
    return truncatedUser as Pick<IUser, ArrayElement<T>>;
  }
}

const user = new User();


const fullUser = user.toJSON(); // full "IUser"
const truncatedUser = user.toJSON({ attributes: ['name'] });

console.log(truncatedUser.age);
console.log(fullUser.age);

fullUser.id // works
truncatedUser.id // should throw an error, but tsc compiles
```

Comment: I didn't try this solution yet in detail, but it looks promising too. So far I've went with solution provided by @merryweather.